# Multiple values update into a new table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

```
     4            7.99          31.96           10
```

invoice

i_invoicenumber       i_invoicedate   i_payment   i_emailaddress    i_subtotal

```
         50       06-FEB-18 Cash         40      John@test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use a subquery:

```
update invoice i
    set subtotal = (select sum(li.li_total)
                    from line_item li
                    where i.invoice_number = li.invoice_number
                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

```
UPDATE invoice i 
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT invoice_number, sum(total) as line_item_total
   FROM line_item
   GROUP BY invoice_number
) li ON i.invoice_number = li.invoice_number
SET i.subtotal = li.line_item_total
```

Comment: I am getting this error ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Comment: Ah...that's a good point.  I didn't test this.  What database are you using?  Can you add a group by to the end of the statement I provided.  `group by li.invoice_number`

Comment: Im using my SQL and im still get the same error code with this after it

Comment: Just tweaked this query to do it a different way.  Give my edited reply a shot...

Comment: @JohnZymbolikJamesZymbolik - if you're using MySQL, why is this question tagged for Oracle?